# New Pandoc distrib = loose cross-references (RMarkdown - knitr - Bookdown - thesisdown - R)

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, bookdown, cross-reference

I've loose some cross-references when exporting a bunch of .Rmd files to a single .doc file, using knitr and bookdown (+ yaml). The method is thesisdown::thesis_word:.

- The problem of loosing-references occurred immediately after I've installed a new version of Pandoc. Maybe I miss a step after Pandoc installation ?
- The lost references are currently the `\@ref(title)` ones, which previously return the number of the title indicated by : `# My title {#title}` and now return `(??)`. Only these anchors are missing, after the install of pandoc. Maybe I have to use another style of anchors for references to a section of the document ?

  - Pandoc seems ok : all references to .bib dictionary, tables and figures anchors are ok (& env. path variables in Microsoft Windows are ok and pointing to the new pandoc.exe).

Thanks a lot for any advice, excellent day.

*PS : I'm using thesisdown (sort of bookdown stuff) and I don't - yet - try a normal bookdown export using knitr... I don't try - yet - another type of exported document (like html or pdf).*

Comment: The first solution I can find is with the hyperlink. These hyperlink work correctly for me in the new version of pandoc, so I've replace all cross-references which an hyperlink, like this kind of cross-reference : `[1](#a-title-name)`. This solution force me to indicate a word or a numbering, in order to made this character an hyperlink to a title of the document (in my e.g., '1').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that install or reinstall [tinytext](https://yihui.org/tinytex/) is the key for solving this problem. If not, just go further with packages update (e.g., bookdown, thesisdown). Sometimes, you need to reinstall Rstudio (solve this kind of problem, or some package update issues).